# Google Sheets API v4 doesn't save mergeCells

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm just trying make cells merged in batchUpdate but they don't. updateDimensionProperties and pasteData works well, but mergeCell not without returning any errors. What I'm doing wrong?

```
results = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId = 'some_weird_spreadsheet_id',
    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "mergeCells": {
                    "mergeType": "MERGE_COLUMNS",
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "endRowIndex": 1,
                        "startColumnIndex": 12,
                        "endColumnIndex": 19
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "mergeCells": {
                    "mergeType": "MERGE_ROWS",
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "endRowIndex": 2,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endColumnIndex": 1
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }).execute()
```

Comment: Have you tested your request with the Google APIs Explorer? Once you know the request, you should be able to figure out how to build it in your current library.

Answer (score 1):

From the ranges of your request body, I thought that you might want to merge the cells of "M1:S1" and "A1:A2", respectively. So how about this modification?

#### Modified request body :

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "mergeCells": 
      {
        "mergeType": "MERGE_ROWS", # Modified
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 12,
          "endColumnIndex": 19
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mergeCells": 
      {
        "mergeType": "MERGE_COLUMNS", # Modified
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 2,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Note :

- I think that in your case, `MERGE_ALL` can be also used for `mergeType`.
- This modification supposes that you can use Sheets API.

#### Reference :

- [MergeType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=ja#mergetype)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Have tried your solution, but nothing happens. GAPI accepts but ignores my requests, without returning any errors. Response is like this: `{'spreadsheetId': 'some_weird_spreadsheet_id', 'replies': [{}, {}]}`

Comment: @Constantin Dolinin I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I think that this returned value is the correct. So can I ask you about what you want? In this modified request body, when it it sees the spreadsheet after the API with the request body was posted, you can confirm that the merged cells of "M1:S1" and "A1:A2". On the other hand, in your request body, "M1:S1" and "A1:A2" are not merged because each value of "mergeType" is not correct for the range. I had thought that your issue was this. But if I misunderstand your issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: I've modified my request with your suggestions before comment writing, also have tried with MERGE_ALL and have no changes in returned by GAPI result

Comment: @Constantin Dolinin I'm sorry for the inconvenience. That returned value is correct value. If an error occurs, other response is returned. So can I ask you about what you want? And was my understanding for your question correct? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: result is OK, yep, but I don't see any changes in target spreadsheet when open it on Google Sheets. This is the problem.

Comment: @Constantin Dolinin About ``I don't see any changes in target spreadsheet when open it on Google Sheets.``, in my environment, when the modified request body is posted using Sheets API, I could confirm that "M1:S1" and "A1:A2" are merged respectively. In your environment, "M1:S1" and "A1:A2" are NOT merged. If my understanding is correct, how about trying [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)? You can use spreadsheets.batchUpdate with the modified request body at "Try this API". In my environment, I confirmed that it also works.